# クラス内からしか呼び出さないメソッドを明示する方法はないでしょうか?

Tags: python

Python 3.4.3を利用しています。

モジュールを自作する中でクラスのインスタンスメソッドの共通の処理を切り出して、他のインスタンスメソッドにしているのですが、後者のインスタンスメソッドは前述のインスタンスメソッド以外に呼び出されないようにしたいです(あるいは、コードを見たときに前述のインスタンスメソッドにしか使わないことがわかるようにしたい)

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_power_two(self, number):  # 2のnumber乗を返す
        answer = 1
        for i in range(0, number):
            answer = self.twice(answer)
        return answer

    def twice(self, answer):  # get_power_two以外からは呼び出されない
        return 2*answer

A = testclass()
print(A.get_power_two(4))  # 16
A.twice(2)  # これがエラーになってほしい
```

上記のコードでは、`get_power_two()`の処理の一部を`twice()`というインスタンスメソッドに切り出していますが、これは`A.twice(2)`と呼び出せてしまいます。 このメソッドが、同じクラス内のメソッド以外から呼び出されない、あるいは呼び出されるべきでないことを明らかにしたいのですが、うまい方法はないでしょうか?
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 8):

メソッド名を `_twice` にしましょう。
Pythonでは、外から使って欲しくないことを表明するために `_` を付けます。
それを無視して使われる可能性はありますが、それは使う方の責任ですね。

`__` を付ける方法もありますが、不自由になりすぎるのでお勧めしません。

Answer (score 2):

`_`(single-underscore) や `__`(double-underscore) の様な `internal use indicator` を利用する以外に `decorator` と `inspect` を使う方法を挙げておきます。

```
def local_method(m):
  import inspect, functools
  @functools.wraps(m)
  def lm(self, answer):
    cls = self.__class__
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals
    if 'self' in caller and cls == caller['self'].__class__:
      return m(self, answer)
    raise Exception("Cannot call `{0}' method outside `{1}' class."
                    .format(m.__name__, cls.__name__))

  return lm

class testclass:
        :

  @local_method
  def twice(self, answer):
    return 2*answer
```

ただし、`self` を参照しているので、`testclass` 内の `classmethod` や `staticmethod` から呼ばれる場合にはエラーになります。

```
class testclass:
        :    

  @classmethod
  def class_method(cls):
    cls().twice(10)       // エラー

  @staticmethod
  def static_method():
    testclass().twice(10) // エラー
```

Answer (score 0):

関数内で関数を定義することもできます：

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_power_two(self, number):  # 2のnumber乗を返す
        def twice(answer):
            return 2 * answer

        answer = 1
        for i in range(0, number):
            answer = twice(answer)
        return answer
```

`twice` は `get_power_two` 以外からはアクセス不可能です。